# Possible to do an iOS app distribution via the web without knowing the device's UDID?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

Is it now possible to use ad-hoc distribution without knowing the authorized devices' UDIDs?

I've just come across [this](http://www.mentor-beta.com/), which basically installs an iOS app on my iOS device, **without** them knowing my device's UDID in advance.

Is that a new functionality on iOS that I've missed or are they exploiting some vulnerability?

Comment: AFAIK this is possible through Enterprise dev a/c In-house distribution provisioning.

Comment: Also, Apple has pretty strict guidelines governing the circumstances under which you can do Enterprise distribution. If you get caught violating them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No this is not possible, for Ad-Hoc distribution you will need to know the UDID of the device on which it will be installed.

The link you provide uses the Enterprise distribution to distribute the app. You are not supposed to have the download of the app publicly available, this is breach of the contract with Apple and could mean that they wil revoke you account.
With the Enterprise Account you can on distribute your app to employees of the company for which the account is registered.